# jqGrid Search toolbar not supporting special characters

Tags: jqgrid

When using Local Filter (with “contains” operator) Toolbar with jqGrid (latest version), it seems that special characters such as ‘@’ or ‘-‘  (dash) cause the Filter to return NO records.
The same problem exists with other operators as well, such as “Begins With” or “Equal”.

The impact is on fields with content that contains ‘@”, such as emails, or in other text fields like phone numbers.

The problem turns out to be encoded HTML source, so '664-5209' would show up as '664&#45;5209' in the HTML source (using local data source).
And indeed, filtering for '664&#45;5209' would show records with '664-5209'.

The question is whether it is possible to modify the user entered dash to &#45; (and for that matter other HTML encoding) before the filter is executed, and how? 
A sample would be helpful.

Comment: add autoencode:true and see what happens

Comment: This idea created a major mess with many other characters, such as ( that were displayed correctly. It seems that autoencode impacts the display. I Was looking for an internal Filter capabilities that will treat user input and encoded text correctly.